# In Xamarin azure, UpdateAsync is not updating database, only changes info locally

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

So my app updates the information inside locally when i call `UpdateSync` on the table but it doesn't update the online database? Am I doing something wrong?

```
IMobileServiceSyncTable<Models.About_user> about_user_table;
Update_my_table(Object Item)
{                
   Models.About_user About_user = (Models.About_user)Item;
   await about_user_table.UpdateAsync(About_user);
   IMobileServiceSyncTable<Models.About_user> about_user_table;
}
```

Comment: reformatted lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code, you are using the sync table (`IMobileServiceSyncTable`), for the `UpdateAsync` operation, it would update your local SQLite database. In order to update your online database, you need to execute the Push operation by using the following code:

```
await Client.SyncContext.PushAsync();
```

**Note:** when executing the push operation, you may need to handle Conflict Resolution. For more details, you could refer to adrian's book about [Handling Conflict Resolution](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/client/#handling-conflict-resolution) and [An Offline Client](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/client/#an-offline-client).

Moreover, you could use `client.GetTable<Model>()` for constructing an online table and do CUD changes against your online table. For more details, you could refer to [here](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/client/#an-online-client). Additionally, you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync) about offline synchronization.

Comment: Thanks, I believe I am calling  a function Synctable after I do the update which does that. But I will implement the try catch in order to catch that conflict

Comment: Any concerns, feel free to let me know.

Comment: Your answer helped guide me towards the answer! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So All I had to is put that on the bottom of my updatesync. Note: this didnt work unless I explicitly had a variable in my about_user model called version like         [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Version")]
        public string Version { get; set; }

```
  await about_user_table.UpdateAsync(About_user);
            try
            {
                await Client.SyncContext.PushAsync();
              ///  await about_user_table.PullAsync("all About_user", about_user_table.CreateQuery());
            }
           catch (MobileServicePushFailedException ex)
           {
                if (ex.PushResult != null)
               {
                   foreach (var error in ex.PushResult.Errors)
                   {
                      await ResolveConflictAsync(error,"about_user_table");
                   }
                }
            }
    async Task ResolveConflictAsync(MobileServiceTableOperationError error, string table_name)
    {
        var serverItem = error.Result.ToObject<About_user>();
        var localItem = error.Item.ToObject<About_user>();



        // Note that you need to implement the public override Equals(TodoItem item)
        // method in the Model for this to work
        if (serverItem.Equals(localItem))
        {
            // Items are the same, so ignore the conflict
            await error.CancelAndDiscardItemAsync();
            return;
        }

        // Client Always Wins
        localItem.Version = serverItem.Version;
        await error.UpdateOperationAsync(JObject.FromObject(localItem));
    }
```